# uitoptop plugin on pages with other jump to links

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I have two pages on a site that have a table of contents of sorts at the top that jump down to that section of the page and then provide a back to top link.

Also, on all pages of the site I am using Matt Varone's UItoTop jQuery Plugin. When using the back to top links or the plugin arrow to get back to the top of the page on a mobile device, something strange is happening to the header of the page--it is being pulled something like 50 pixels higher than it should be which obscures the link to the mobile menu.

Here's a snippet of the javascript used in the plugin---

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var sd = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(typeof document.body.style.maxHeight === "undefined") {
    $(containerIDhash).css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'top': $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - 50
            });
```

Maybe something with the 50 in there? Changing the number doesn't seem to make a difference though; still same problem...

To see this happening, size your browser down to mobile width and see here:

[live link](http://lisat-alachua2.migwebtech.com/app_pages/view/242#EducatorsCommittee)

I am thinking the page is confused by the various anchor tags on the page...? I haven't found here or anywhere else a similar problem. Anyone else come across this issue? Works fine on other screen widths. Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Upon removing the uitotop plug in, the problem persists, so this question is not valid.